# Launching a .sh file from a launcher

Tags: command-line, launcher, .desktop

I am fairly new to Ubuntu 14.04. I am doing a school project where I need to use navigation stacks. At this point the navigation works fine. My problem at this time is:
Before I can launch `rviz` and to do the actual navigation I have to execute the following commands:

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS51 c 4 115  
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS51, TCP4:192.168.0.60:10002  
sudo chmod a=r+w /dev/pts/*
```

There are some extra commands I need to run, but I think you guys get the picture.
At this point I have to manually enter all these commands into the terminal. I have added them to a shell file which I can launch manually.

I would like to know if it is possible to execute this shell file from a `.launch` file. The same way a node is launched from within a `.launch` file.
It would make it a lot easier if I can add a piece of code to the existing launch file so that these commands and the rest of the nodes necessary for the navigation are executed when I input the following command:

```
roslaunch navigation2d_example move_base.launch
```

The name of my shell file is: `mobi_mani.sh`
Code inside is:

```
#!/bin/sh  
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/ttyS51 c 4 115  
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyS51, TCP4:192.168.0.60:10002  
sudo chmod a=r+w /dev/pts/* "
```

Long story short.
How can I execute the commands stated in a `.sh` file from a `.launch` file?
Also, can I get feedback on the screen of my terminal? so I know what is going on.

Apologies for my English, I am Dutch.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ha Gijs, just curious, did you manage? please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the information, due to some holidays I have not been able to test it. Tuesday, Dutch time, will be the first possibility for me to test it out. Will keep you posted!

Comment: the desktop file works. I only have one unresolved issue: how can i get information back from the different commands? For example: after executing a command i expect to receive some text data telling me if the command is successful. How do I get this information into the terminal window after it launches?

Comment: Hi Gijs, try adding a line to the `.desktop` file: `Terminal=true` possibly you'll need to edit the terminal preferences to keep it open after the command ran. Let me know!

Comment: Ha Gijs, did it work?

Comment: No it didn't work.  I already had set terminal to true and couldn't find anyway to keep the terminal open. But I'm also having trouble executing commands that do not return the command line. It doesn't seem to be executing those commands. Sometimes the shell opens and I'm prompted for password and then it seems the rest isn't correctly executed.   I tried using a shell file and both options you gave me. I still didn't get it to work.

Comment: See my updated answer. If you do it like that, it cannot fail :). Remove in this case the line `Terminal=true`, since the command already calls `gnome-terminal`

Comment: Gijs, did you manage?

Comment: Okay, so now it stays open! The next problem is that I want to launch roscore and other commands that don't return the command line. How do I do this?

Comment: I think it is in the answer already (first section). If you need specific info on specific commands, I'd suggest asking a new question. Since this one seems to be answered, would you consider accepting it (below the up/down arrows on the left). It also makes clear the answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are referring to a `.desktop` file. These files can be used to run commands, applications etc.

The most basic version of a `.desktop`file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Some Name
Exec=<command> 
Type=Application
```

In your case, you want to run a *series* of commands, using `sudo`. In that case you need:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Some Name
Exec=/bin/bash -c "command1&&command2&&command3"
Type=Application
Terminal=true
```

You need to save the file with the extension `.desktop`, e.g. `run_commands.desktop`. To use these files from the desktop, make it executable.

#### Explanation

- To use complicated commands in a `.desktop`file, the `Exec=` line should look like:

  ```
  Exec=/bin/bash -c "command1&&command2&&command3"
  ```
- to chain commands in a `.desktop` file, as if each command would be on a new line in a script, you have to use `&&` between the commands.
- If you use `sudo` in a command, you need to either set:

  ```
  Terminal=true
  ```

  so the commands will run in the terminal and ask you for the password, or you need to use `gksu` instead of `sudo`, so `gksu`will ask you for your password. In that case, you would have to install `gksu`, which is not by default on your system:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gksu
  ```

#### If the command is too complicated or too long to handle in a .desktop file

If your series of commands is too long to handle in a `.desktop` file, write them in a small script, like you did, and call the script from the `.desktop` file. The `Exec=` line in the `.desktop` file should then look like:

```
Exec=/bin/sh mobi_mani.sh
```

---

### EDIT if you need to run commands in the terminal

You can also use the following to run commands from the terminal: 
Set in the `.desktop`file as `Exec=` line:

```
Exec=gnome-terminal -x /bin/bash -c "<command1>&&<command2>&&<command3>"
```

Then, assuming you use `gnome-terminal`, go to Preferences (gnome-terminal) > Profile Preferences > Title & Command, then from the dropdown list "When command it finished" > keep terminal open:

[image]

This practically cannot fail.