# How to run a python script as sudo by double-clicking it?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo, gksu

Simply put, how can I do this, providing a graphical prompt?

I tried creating a separate bash script that when opened, ran the Python script with super-user permissions - I used `gksu -u root '<script>'`.

Unfortunately, it didn't work... :(

Any ideas?

Comment: creating a `.desktop` file with the command `gksu python3 /path/to/script` should work. Must be a dupe of something.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I've looked a **LOT** and can't find anything. Why a `.desktop` file?

Comment: A `.desktop` file is the appropriate GUI way to start any process or application via GUI, similar to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/626434/launching-a-sh-file-from-a-launcher/626513#626513. Alternatively, you can set nautilus to run executable scripts on double- click, but I'd prefer the general way.

Comment: @JacobVlijm thanx, could you post an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appropriate way to start any process or application via GUI is using a `.desktop` file. You can also use it to run scripts with `sudo` privileges. In its simplest form that would be:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Some Name
Exec=gksu python3 /path/to/script 
Type=Application
```

If the script is executable, you could simply use:

```
Exec=gksu /path/to/script
```

In the `Exec=` -line

#### important notes

- You need to make the `.desktop` file executable to make it work on double- click.
- You can "dress up" the `.desktop` file with more options, such as an icon etc., as [shown here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

#### Alternatively

More complicated and kind of a detour, but it should be mentioned nevertheless:
You *could* set `nautilus` to run (executable) scripts on double- click, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286621/how-do-i-run-executable-scripts-in-nautilus).

Then (doing it "your way"), a separate bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
gksu python3 /path/to/script
```

made executable, would also run the python script, similarly to the `.desktop` file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not enough rep to commet. 
Did your try giving the file the correct permissions.
Try giving rwx to everyone to see if that works, you can change it to your desired setting later.

```
sudo chmod 777 'script.py'.
```

Try this to fix the path problem

```
gksudo ./script
```

Comment: my problem is that when the sudo GUI prompt comes up and I enter the password, nothing opens...

Comment: I see. I know this isn’t the answer, but why are you using gksu in the first place ?

Comment: I think your problem is you're calling something in the current working directory. You have to incldue that in your agrument

Comment: ' gksudo ./script'  should do it